# How can PHPUnit code coverage ignore my autoloader?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, code-coverage, zend-autoloader

I have a bootstrap in my phpunit config that runs the `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader.php`.  I can get PHPUnit code coverage to ignore it when I add

```
<filter>
   <blacklist>
       <directory suffix=".php">/absolute/path/to/zf</directory>
   </blacklist>
</filter>
```

to the PHPUnit config XML file.  But I have to specify an absolute path.  I want it to be a relative path but PHPUnit is not ignoring the Zend folder in the code coverage.  I don't want to add different location for when I'm working at home and I don't want other developers adding their own paths.  The Zend Framework is in the php.ini `include_path` setting but this does not work:

```
<filter>
   <blacklist>
       <directory suffix=".php">./Zend</directory>
   </blacklist>
</filter>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can exclude paths from the code coverage with the `<exclude>...</exclude>` directive within your `<filter><whitelist>`:

```
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../src/library/</directory>
        <!-- add more directories -->
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".phtml">./src/application/</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">./Zend/</directory>
            <!-- add more directories with relative or absolute path -->
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Comment: Why you added `suffix` argument to excluded directories?

Answer (score 1):

Actually this can be done with a blacklist as well. The path needs to be relative to your tests directory.

This did the trick in my project:

```
<filter>
    <blacklist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../../../cache</directory>
    </blacklist>
</filter>
```