# PHPUnit - how to ignore code coverage for classloader?

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

When I generate code coverage for my PHP project, I always get the Symfony autoloader.

I tried adding  this to my PHPUnit config with no luck:

```
<filter>
    <blacklist>
        <directory>/Symfony/Component</directory>
    </blacklist>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you didn't specified suffix attribute to search for specific type of file in blacklist

so it should be

```
<filter>
    <blacklist>
        <directory suffix=".php">/Symfony/Component</directory>
    </blacklist>
</filter>
```

if this is not working for you then you can use exclude tag in whitelist block

```
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../src/library/</directory>
        <!-- add more directories -->
        <exclude>
            <directory suffix=".php">./Zend/</directory>
            <!-- add more directories with relative or absolute path -->
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Reference: [How can PHPUnit code coverage ignore my autoloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11400545/1237812)

Comment: I tried adding the suffix with no luck. I was going to try the whitelist approach (though it seems to me the blacklist approach should work) but am not sure what the path would be when I am running the project in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using composer and tried several variations including the exclusion within a whitelist:

My directory structure is thus:

```
...
/project/tests
/project/vendor
/project/vendor/composer
...
```

I tried to get whitelist working:

```
<whitelist>
    <exclude>
        <directory suffix=".php">..\vendor\composer\</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">../vendor/composer/</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">..\composer\</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">../composer/</directory>
    </exclude>
</whitelist>
```

That did not work. But this did:

```
<filter>
    <blacklist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../vendor/composer</directory>
    </blacklist>
</filter>
```

My configuration xml file is within the tests folder along with a bootstrap file that loads in composer's autoloader.

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__. str_repeat(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '..', 1) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php');
```